# VBA Library not Registered Run Time Error '-2147319779 (8002801d)'

Tags: excel, vba

`I currently use the following VBA to create my quarterly reports.

```
'Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application   
 Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
 Dim shp As Object
 Dim myTextBox As Object
 Dim PPTTitle As String
 Dim PPTFooter As String
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim q As Integer
 Dim ChrtstoCopy As Integer
 Dim TblstoCopy As Integer
 Dim Firstslide As Boolean
 Dim CurrentSite As String
 Dim shortDeptName As String
 Sub CopytoPPT(Lbox_Exp, Lbox_Lis, Lbox_Rec)

 'ACTIVATED BY: Userform2 Command Button
 'PURPOSE: Copy the printareas for slides 1-5 in picture format and then 
  paste to a PPT slide.

 'Identify the criteria for the PPT slides
  CurrentSite = UserForm2.SiteTbox.Value
  ChrtstoCopy = Slide1_Sht.Range("S19").Value - 1
  TblstoCopy = Slide5_Sht.Range("D5").Value
  Firstslide = True
  If UserForm2.CheckBox1 = True Then
  blinded = " (Blinded)"
  Else
  blinded = " (Unblinded)"
  End If

 shortDeptName = 
 TgtSht.Range("SaveFileName").Find(What:=CurrentSite).Offset(0, 1).Text
 fileNameString = TgtSht.Range("SaveFolder") & TgtSht.Range("SavePrefix") & 
  " - " & shortDeptName

  'Open PPT application and existing blank PPT template file
   Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
   ppApp.Visible = True
```

The VBA is used to paste my data into graphs presented in a power point. Recently my desktop got updated to a 64 bit and when I try to run my VBA to produce the power point I need it gives me the following error message. 
Run-time error '-2147319779 (8002801d)':
Automation error 
Library not registered

I tried to further investigate what could possibly be causing this and I believe it may be related to the command "Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application".

When I try to just run the Macro for PasteImgtoPPT I get a 
Run-time error '91': 
Object variable or with block variable not set error.

I have been trying for weeks to fix this VBA but can't seem to find the solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the actual code, not a screenshot of it?

Comment: Also include the error messages as text, not as screen shots. You might want to take a moment to read about asking questions on Stack Overflow in the site [help] in order to get fast, effective assistance...

Comment: Open the Tools->References dialog. Anything in there that's 32bit only?

Comment: Please stop re-adding the snippet markdown. That's for Java\Html and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you don't have `Microsoft Powerpoint` reference made in the project, so trying to declare a variable that makes reference to powerpoint is going to fail (your project has no idea what that is).

To tell your project about it (make the reference) go to Tools>>References and find it in the list:

[image]

Check it, and click "OK" then try to execute your VBA again.

You can also consider late binding your powerpoint variables so you don't have to reference them:

```
 Dim ppApp As Object  
 Dim ppSlide As Object
 Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
 Set ppSlide = PPApp.Slide
```

`CreateObject` loads the reference to `Powerpoint.Application` at runtime.